# html_safe on whole html code block in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, html-safe

i can't seem to find a way to escape whole html block, if it is even possible.

Here is what i am trying to do:

```
%table
  %tr
    %th{rowspan: "2"}= t("public.home.graphic_title_payment").html_safe
    %th.datefield{rowspan: "2"}= t("public.home.graphic_title_dates").html_safe
    %th{colspan: "3"}= t("public.home.graphic_title_pay_group").html_safe
    %th{rowspan: "2"}= t("public.home.graphic_title_unpaid").html_safe
```

Altho i dont like purring `.html_safe` at the end of every string. Is there a way i could maybe put some kind of indicator that all `%tr` needs to be html_safe??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails escapes ERB output by default. So the best thing would probably be to create a new helper method to run the I18n translation and mark it as safe. So perhaps:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def st(translation)
  t(translation).html_safe
end
```

Then:

```
%th{rowspan: "2"}= st("public.home.graphic_title_payment")
```

Comment: thx for answer, that is what i did almost instantly when i finished question :) but i still wanted to know if there is a way to do this for blocks...

Comment: You *could* do a whole block if you were producing the HTML as well inside of that block. Otherwise each ERB output into the HTML needs to be escaped. Also, it's a dangerous way of thinking to simply mark everything as safe so it's not supposed to be easy :)